# phantomjs: command not found

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, phantomjs

I followed [these instructions](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/BuildInstructions) (except for copying the executable to my PATH because I cannot seem to find it and it does not seem necessary). Then I made a file called image_render.js in my public javascripts directory with

```js
console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.exit();
```

inside it, saved it, and ran `phantomjs render_image.js` in my terminal. 
However, my terminal does not recognize the command:

```
-bash: phantomjs: command not found
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `PATH` really is the important part. You can skip it, however, if you specify the absolute path. Try something like this:

```
/path/to/phantomjs render_image.js
```

...but that can get tiring. For a quick way to add it to your `PATH`, from the directory of the `phantomjs` executable, symbolically link it into `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/
```

`/usr/local/bin` is likely on your `PATH`.

Comment: where do I find the executable? where exactly do I put it? in my root?

Comment: @user730569: Check the `bin` folder. If you're on Linux, it should be right in there. If you're on Mac OS X, it should be in `phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS`, which should be in there.

Comment: I'm not sure where this `bin` folder is. I'm on Mac OSX

Comment: @user730569: Assuming you just opened up a terminal and copied the code from the build instructions web page into there, the `bin` directory should be in the `phantomjs` directory in your home directory.

Comment: @user730569: If you couldn't access it by typing `phantomjs`, it *isn't* on your `PATH`. That's why you need to link it to somewhere that is, as I showed in my answer. Alternatively, you could add something to your `PATH`, but that's a little more complex.

Comment: I put it into `/usr/local/bin` and `phantomjs` does not work so it must not be on my `PATH`. How do I find out my `PATH`?

Comment: this is what I get: `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin`... the executable is currently on my desktop
`

Comment: @user730569: If that's your `PATH` and the `phantomjs` executable is in `/usr/local/bin`, it should work. Did you use an absolute path when linking it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I typed `sudo ln -s /path/to/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/` but maybe I didn't get the path to the executable correct? what would the path be now that it's on my desktop?

Comment: @user730569: The `/path/to/phantomjs` was a placeholder. Replace `/path/to/phantomjs` with the absolute path to the PhantomJS executable. If your username (the UNIX one, not the full name) was `johndoe`, the absolute path to your executable might be `/Users/johndoe/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs`.

Comment: @user730569: If it's on your desktop it might be `/Users/johndoe/Desktop/phantomjs` (if it's the executable and *not* the `.app`), but you'll have to keep it on your desktop unless it's copied, so that's no good.

Comment: my UNIX username? sorry I'm really bad at this

Comment: @user730569: It may be displayed at your `bash` prompt as `username@host`. Take the `username` part. Aside: if you're going to be programming using PhantomJS or other things, you'll probably want to get acquainted with the shell.

Comment: this is displayed at the prompt: `new-computers-computer:~ newcomputer$`

Comment: @user730569: In that case, it's the word just before the `$`.

Comment: so I ran `sudo ln -s /Users/newcomputer/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs  /usr/local/bin/` but still no luck :/

Comment: my shell is telling me `/Users/newcomputer/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs` doesn't exist

Comment: ok so `/Users/newcomputer/phantomjs` doesn't exist but `/Users/newcomputer` does

Comment: @user730569: Where did you execute the build instructions from?

Comment: ahh ok, this is the path to phantomjs `/rubyprograms/search/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs`... exactly, I executed the instructions from inside my app

Comment: ok I've figured it out. Thanks!!!! God help me when I have to do this on linux haha, this was just for local development

Answer (score 5):

add this line to this file /home/optiman2/.bashrc

```
PATH=/home/optiman2/phantomjs/bin:$PATH
```

this worked for me.

and remember to use this command, before test phantomjs:
source .bashrc

Comment: add export PATH after the above line

Answer (score 1):

FYI to Windows users upgrading to version 2.0.0 - the executable has moved. In addition to changing your PATH environment variable to 2.0.0, you'll need to add `\bin` to the end of the PATH that you had for the 1.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

Mac PATH suggested setup:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Type `vi ~/.bash_profile` and hit enter (this opens or creates your bash_profile where you can customize Terminal commands).
3. Press `i` to enter insert/edit mode then type `alias phantomjs='~/PATH/TO/phantomjs'` and be sure to replace `~/PATH/TO/phantomjs` with something like `~/Documents/PhantomJS/bin/phantomsj` or wherever the file exists on your machine.
4. Press `esc` to exit insert/edit mode then type `:x` and hit enter to save the file.
5. Quit and re-open Terminal.
6. Type `phantomjs` and hit enter. If you see the prompt `phantomjs>` then you're all set.
7. Type `phantom.exit()` to end the PhantomJS program.
8. Now you can navigate to any folder and run PhantomJS by simply typing `phantomjs`. This is helpful when saving screenshots because the images will be saved inside the folder that's active in your Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever command is just a executable file. To be accessible by type its name directly, you have to put it into a path that system will look for that file directly.
For linux/OSX, it's **/usr/bin** or **/usr/local/bin**. Which really works? Well, it depends...
So what worked for me is extract the 'phantomjs.tar.bz2' source file to somewhere and copy the executable file to */usr/local/bin* like this:

`cp path-of-extracted-phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin`