# How can I set up & run PhantomJS on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, phantomjs

I set up PhantomJS and recorded it to video: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/xnizmh_1_webcam

Build instructions: http://phantomjs.org/build.html

Is there anything wrong in my setup?

After I set it up I read the [quick start tutorial](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Quick-Start) and tried to write this code

```
phantomjs hello.js
```

It gives me "command not found" error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what's the output of whereis phatomjs ?

Comment: Try this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448459/phantomjs-not-working

Comment: it give me " phantomjs: " output

Comment: i tried it it gives me same error :(

Comment: thank you i solved the problem. The problem is i dont have softlink for my program. Thanks for ur help :)

Comment: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-phantomjs-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Guidouil's answer put me on the right track. I had to add one additional symlink to /usr/bin/, and I did direct symlinks for all 3 - see below.

I'm installing on Ubuntu server Natty Narwhal.

This is exactly what I did.

```
cd /usr/local/share
sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo tar xjf phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

And finally when I do

```
phantomjs -v
```

I get 1.9.7

If anyone sees any problems with what I've done, please let me know.

Comment: if you need that final sym link it is because you don't have /usr/local/bin in your PATH

Comment: I am getting error on this command   sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.8.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs': No such file or directory

Comment: Please check before downloading the tar file via terminal:
    uname -i

Comment: @AmarBanerjee you need to use sudo in front of the previous and while unwrapping the tar ball.

Comment: This works, but can anyone explain to me why shouldn't we just copy paste the whole thing into `usr/bin` instead of creating a link to `/usr/local`?

Comment: Anyone get permission denied too?

Comment: Thank you for this prebuild link, as i coulnt get it to build on Ubuntu

Comment: For phantomjs to be available from any directory, it is enough if you add a symlink to one of the directories listed in your $PATH variable. (run "echo $PATH" to see which they are).

Comment: I ran into this issue: bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. I found a fix [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10904). Run the command: `sudo apt-get install libfontconfig`

Comment: Nice answer mate. I knew that but I was not dare to do that. Your answer encourages me and it is on progress.

Comment: I put these commands in my CI build steps. They worked fine…until the CI server started getting 403 errors from bitbucket.org. (I'm guessing it's rate-limiting.) So I found [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533707/bitbucket-rate-limiting-phantomjs#39533708) and changed the URL to `https://cnpmjs.org/mirrors/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2`.

Comment: could you please chek this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624964/phantom-js-on-web-project

Answer (score 116):

PhantomJS is on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-prebuilt). You can run this command to install it globally:

```
npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt
```

`phantomjs -v` should return `2.1.1`

Comment: +1 on Ubuntu this gives version ```1.9.7``` as opposed to ```1.4.0```.

Comment: +1 for using `npm` but see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25953078/881743)

Comment: If bitbucket.org is blocked by your proxy `npm install phantomjs --phantomjs_cdnurl=http://cnpmjs.org/downloads`

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, this now gives me `2.1.1`.

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04 I get an error, that I should run it as root. With `sudo` it works: `sudo npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt`

Answer (score 58):

download from phantomjs website the prebuilt package :
http://phantomjs.org/download.html
then open a terminal and go to the Downloads folder

```
sudo mv phantomjs-1.8.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 /usr/local/share/.
cd /usr/local/share/
sudo tar xjf phantomjs-1.8.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.8.1-linux-x86_64 /usr/local/share/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

then to check install `phantomjs -v` should return `1.8.1`

Comment: Why do you create a link instead of copy paste directly?

Comment: Why would you copy paste directly when you can symlink? =/

Comment: on a fresh ubuntu also apt-get install libfontconfig

Comment: I had phantomjs installed in my user directory. Selenium didn't work with that. I then moved phantomjs to `/usr/local/share` and created these symbolic links. Then it worked (even though file permissions were the same). Can anyone explain to this non-linux-expert why this made a difference?

Answer (score 38):

**Install from package manager:**

```
sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```

Comment: Sadly, this now installs 1.4, which is so old many things that use phantom.js just won't work.

Comment: @JulianBirch Yes, I think if you have in Ubuntu Saucy Salamander(13.10) you can get the 1.9.0 version according to this [link] https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phantomjs, I just installed from  Raring Ringtail(13.04) and I get 1.6.0 version,like it also say in the link

Comment: Installed 1.9.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: But I recommend to install it via [`npm install -g phantomjs`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22524611/1420197).

Comment: Just installed. It's 1.9.0 now.

Answer (score 14):

**Here are the build steps I used** (note these instructions are for version 1.3. See comments to this answer for the installation instructions of the latest PhantomJS):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libqtwebkit-dev qt4-qmake
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git && cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.3
qmake-qt4 && make
```

[Now install Xvfb](http://cisight.com/run-latest-phantomjs-with-shell_exec-php-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/)

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
```

**Launch Xvfb:**
`Xvfb :23 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &`

**Now run phantom:**
`DISPLAY=:23 ./phantomjs hello.js`

Comment: These instructions are now obsolete, in the current version (1.5) there is no need to install either qt or xfvb. See http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Installation

Comment: Michel is correct, the latest version of phantom should be used because it doesn't require a virtual display (Xvfb)

Comment: Answer from Andre was quicker and easier for me.

Answer (score 11):

For PhantomJS version above 1.5, consider this (verbatim copy of the build instructions on the phantom website):

> For Ubuntu Linux (tested on a barebone install of Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid
>   Lynx and Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal):
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath git-core libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev
> git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
> cd phantomjs
> git checkout 1.7
> ./build.sh
> ```

Comment: I think it should be noted (as it is on PhantomJS website) that building from source can take a **very long** time (hours on a small machine).

Comment: It should also be noted that this answer resolved the issue I had with phantomjs when using the prebuilt binaries failed. It took around 1 hour to compile on 2gb ubuntu 10.04 dual core virtual.

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu you can use the prebuilt versions [downloadable from the PhantomJS site](http://phantomjs.org/download.html).

If you have some serious time on your hands you can also [build it yourself](http://phantomjs.org/build.html). (This is exactly the procedure from Nikhil's answer).

The guys over at PhantomJS recommend using the binaries to save time:

> Warning: Compiling PhantomJS from source takes a long time, mainly due to thousands of files in the WebKit module. With 4 parallel compile jobs on a modern machine, the entire process takes roughly 30 minutes. It is highly recommended to download and install the ready-made binary package if it is available.

With a modern machine they mean > 4 cores, > 8gb mem I think. I tried it on a micro AWS instance and gave up after 2 hours.

In short: install the prebuilt packages from the PhantomJS site per their instructions.

Answer (score 4):

Personaly I prefer using `npm` (see [Arnel Bucio answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22524611/881743))

```
sudo npm install -g phantomjs
```

but! I noticed that some of `npm` module still can't see it as global executable.

[image]

so!

- Create new `/usr/share/phantomjs/` directory link

  ```
  cd /usr/share
  sudo ln -s ../lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom phantomjs
  ```
- Remove old `/usr/bin/phantomjs` executable link and create the new one

  ```
  cd /usr/bin
  sudo mv phantomjs phantomjs.old
  sudo ln -s ../share/phantomjs .
  ```

Comment: Doing the commands after broke it for me on Ubuntu 14.04. Works with just the `npm` install, and `sudo apt-get install libfontconfig` after.

Answer (score 3):

in my vagrant bootstrap:

```
apt-get install -y build-essential chrpath git-core libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.9
echo y | ./build.sh
ln -s /home/vagrant/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
cd ..
```

Comment: @artjom b: this would be better as a comment than an edit.
"You don't have to forget to put the resulting executable from ./build.sh into a directory that is in the PATH environment variable. This can be done via symlink as in this example."

Comment: You don't have to forget to put the resulting executable from `./build.sh` into a directory that is in the PATH environment variable. This can be done via symlink as in this example.

Comment: That's what all the other answers forget when using `build.sh`. I only wanted to improve your answer by making that fact more visible. If you don't want it there, fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have done with this.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath git-core libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.9
./build.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

See link 
Installation guide is in ...

> https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620

And run in terminal with this command

> phantomjs --webdriver=4444

Answer (score 1):

From the official site: [phantomjs site](http://phantomjs.org/build.html)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath git-core libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.8
./build.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu, download the suitable file from http://phantomjs.org/download.html. CD to the downloaded folder. Then:

```
sudo tar xvf phantomjs-1.9.0-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo mv phantomjs-1.9.0-linux-x86_64 /usr/local/share/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

Make sure to replace the file name in these commands with the file you have downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware this is definitely one way to do it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install phantomjs
$ phantomjs -v
1.6.0
```

Sadly, it installs 1.6 and not the latest one, but this works for my purposes.

Comment: This installs version `1.9.0-1` now

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too old, but, just i case someone gets to this question from Google now, you can install it by typing apt-get install phantomjs

Comment: It installs X11

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu for Windows, I found neither `apt-get` nor `npm` versions worked for me. What worked was the script from [this comment](https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620#gistcomment-1958591).

For ease of use, I pasted the whole thing into a script file called `install_phantomjs.sh`, made it executable (`chmod u+x install_phantomjs.sh`), and then ran it (`./install_phantomjs.sh`)

Answer (score 0):

Or the latest - 32bit version Linux

```
sudo wget http://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-i686.tar.bz2

sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs

sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs

sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

Answer (score 0):

[Installation and Calling Phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12948#issuecomment-131267076)

Follow the steps doesn't work, but cloned from others built. (ver2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Bellow the installation procedure by Julio Napurí https://gist.github.com/julionc

Version: 1.9.8

Platform: x86_64

First, install or update to the latest system software.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev
```

Install these packages needed by PhantomJS to work correctly.

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev
```

Get it from the PhantomJS website.

```
cd ~
export PHANTOM_JS="phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64"
wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
sudo tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
```

Once downloaded, move Phantomjs folder to /usr/local/share/ and create a symlink:

```
sudo mv $PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/share
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
```

Now, It should have PhantomJS properly on your system.

```
phantomjs --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this simpler way - Phantom dependencies + Npm

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev
```

and npm

```
[sudo] npm install -g phantomjs
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

On linux to run hello.js don't forget to add the path of hello.js:

phantomjs YourPathToPhantomjsFolder/examples/hello.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use phantomjs easily, you can use it at phantomjscloud.com
You can get the result just by http request.

Comment: This wasn't what the OP asked for at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was my fault

Answer (score 0):

This is how I place a specific version of phantomjs in /usr/local/bin on my docker containers.

```
curl -Ls https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v1.9.19/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 \
    | tar jxvf - --strip-components=2 -C /usr/local/bin/ ./phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
```

or with out `./` depending on OS.

```
curl -Ls https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v1.9.19/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 \
    | tar jxvf - --strip-components=2 -C /usr/local/bin/ phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get up and running without `sudo` or `npm`. Simply **download**, **extract**, and **add to path**.

This has the added advantage of **easy backup** if you are in the habit of backing up your entire home folder which I highly recommend. This also works with any version of Linux.

```
➤  cd ~
➤  wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
➤  mkdir phantomjs
➤  tar xjf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 -C phantomjs
➤  echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/phantomjs/bin"' >> .profile
➤  source .profile
➤  phantomjs -v
2.1.1
```

The disadvantages are:

1. You will need to manually upgrade
2. Other users will not have access to this.

You could use a very simple shell script for installing/upgrading

```
#!/bin/sh
# install_phantomjs.sh $VERSION

$VERSION = $1
printf "Downloading PhantomJS $VERSION...\n"
wget "https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-$VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2"

printf "Extracting PhantomJS $VERSION to ~/phantomjs...\n"
mkdir ~/phantomjs
tar xjf phantomjs-$VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 -C ~/phantomjs

printf "Done! Make sure $HOME/phantomjs/bin is in your path.\n"
```

Or in a Dockerfile

```
# Download and setup PhantomJS
ENV PHANTOMJS_VERSION 2.1.1
RUN curl -fSL "https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-$PHANTOMJS_VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2" -o /tmp/phantomjs.tar.bz2 && \
  mkdir ~/phantomjs && \
  tar xjf /tmp/phantomjs.tar.bz2 -C ~/phantomjs && \
  rm /tmp/phantomjs.tar.bz2
ENV PATH /home/$USERNAME/phantomjs/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what I did** 
on my ubuntu 16.04 machine

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo mv path/where/you/downloaded/phantomjs  /usr/bin
```

and finally when I do

```
phantomjs -v
```

I get **2.1.1**

After going through every answer of this thread. I think this is the best solution for installing and running phantomjs in ubuntu.