# Installing phantomjs on ubuntu 11

Tags: installation, phantomjs

I've followed two installation guides, this one: http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Installation

and this one:
http://yoodey.com/comment/10803

Both times, the problem is that the bin directory is supposed to contain a file named phantomjs, yet it does not.  For the first guide it only contains a Info.plist file, and in the second one the bin is empty.

Comment: I have solved this with another stackoverflow question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778513/how-can-i-setup-run-phantomjs-on-ubuntu/9246272#9246272

However, before the last two steps, you must do this:

ln -s dir/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs

where dir is the directory you installed phantomjs in, which should just be your current working directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I setup & run PhantomJS on Ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778513/how-can-i-setup-run-phantomjs-on-ubuntu)