# Is there a way to use PhantomJS in Python?

Tags: python, phantomjs

I want to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) in [Python](http://www.python.org/). I googled this problem but couldn't find proper solutions.

I find `os.popen()`  may be a good choice. But I couldn't pass some arguments to it.

Using `subprocess.Popen()` may be a proper solution for now. I want to know whether there's a better solution or not.

Is there a way to use PhantomJS in Python?

Comment: My answer below tells you how to do it. Just looking at your question and actually thats exactly what Selenium does, a `subprocess.popen` but with some extended features to make the api seamless.

Comment: @flyer: You should probably consider changing the accepted answer, see below. Thank you.

Answer (score 389, accepted):

The easiest way to use PhantomJS in python is via Selenium. The simplest installation method is

1. Install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/)
2. Using Node's package manager install phantomjs: `npm -g install phantomjs-prebuilt`
3. install selenium (in your virtualenv, if you are using that)

After installation, you may use phantom as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # or add to your PATH
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768) # optional
driver.get('https://google.com/')
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png') # save a screenshot to disk
sbtn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.gbqfba')
sbtn.click()
```

If your system path environment variable isn't set correctly, you'll need to specify the exact path as an argument to `webdriver.PhantomJS()`.  Replace this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # or add to your PATH
```

... with the following:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')
```

References:

- http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
- [How do I set a proxy for phantomjs/ghostdriver in python webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699718/how-do-i-set-a-proxy-for-phantomjs-ghostdriver-in-python-webdriver/15699530#15699530)
- https://dzone.com/articles/python-testing-phantomjs

Comment: This worked beautifully, and probably saved me days. Thank you. If one wants the whole rendered page back as source, it's `driver.page_source`.

Comment: Also using [error_handler](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html) parameter when initializing PhantomJS WebDriver one can verify the status code is 200 or otherwise

Comment: This does work beautifully, and I'm pleasantly surprised because http://phantomjs.org/faq.html says "not a Node.js module" --yet the npm wrapper at https://npmjs.org/package/phantomjs makes it behave for this purpose.  In my case I wanted to do this: `bodyStr= driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").get_attribute("innerHTML")` and ...it worked!

Comment: Just to offer my experience after following the advice of avoiding Ghost's dependency complexities. After fully going down the road of PhantomJS, I found myself forking and then recompiling Phantom because their interface to the underlying QT libraries expected too much configuration through command line arguments. So in avoiding complexity, I found myself writing C++ to modify an interface that is too simplified. Not to say that Phantomjs is bad advice, I would just advise to look into its limitations first as it's compilation time is about 20 minutes minimum if you need to modify its source.

Comment: I agree that ghost has crazy dependencies, and I actually failed to get it up and running even after installing millions of X11 related libraries. Ghost is a horror story.

Comment: @brandon I am surprised you needed to recompile phantomjs ... I am curious about the usecase/brickwall you faced with vanilla phantomjs

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This will probably save me a lot of time :-)

Comment: I get "WebDriverException :Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver"
I couldn't find what might cause this error. Can any one help? I'm using python 2.7 with windows.

Comment: @phabtar You need to pass the path to phantomjs as the first argument to PhantomJS ... or fix your windows syspath to be able to see phantomjs.

Comment: I was using sub process, but this is truly better.

Comment: Before this would run successfully, I had to create and give permission to the log file at /var/log/phantomjs/ghostdriver.log

Comment: After hitting my head against trying to copy paste the examples from phantomjs and casperjs I gave up and giving this a try. Not to say they are horrible, I used webdriver before, and the ability to switch browser (phantomjs doesn't work with some sites) is a huge win.

Comment: I had some issues getting this to work I had both execvp(): Permission denied errors when running phantomjs from console, or Can not connect to GhostDriver errors. The solution was to run sudo phantomjs once and from then on it works fine. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11614

Comment: ABORT. EJECT. Avoid phantomjs for python. Waste of time. "Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver." Into eternity. Dev admitted to not updating something or other. Wish I knew this before spending hours trying to breathe life into phantomjs.

Comment: @Amalgovinus I did notice this occasionally, it is something that happens if you run out of memory IIRC. Do you know where the link is to that dev material you mention. I would like to read-up on it.

Comment: PhantomJS was installed in AppData. Is there a permanent fix besides specifying it as an argumentÉ

Comment: @macdonjo yes, make it visible on your system $PATH variable

Comment: Thanks, I did that earlier as a guess, but still can't get the error to go away. So strange. I think I'll make an independent thread.

Comment: Dumb question : why do I have to install node-js? is there no other way to get pahantomJs?

Comment: @Elidosa not a dumb question, its a sys admin style question ... not wanting to install what you don't need. Phantomjs is written in nodejs, thats why you need it in this case. Some distros have packages for phantomjs that will install nodejs behind the scenes.

Comment: Selenium does not allow full control over PhantomJS such as handling callbacks.

Comment: @Pykler PhantomJS is **not** written in node. It's written in C++ and is a headless webkit browser. The node package just installs the appropriate binary.

Comment: Under Windows, I did not have to install `phantomJS` via `node` and `npm`. Downloading the binary from http://phantomjs.org/download.html and putting the `phantomjs.exe` into a location in my PATH (e.g. `c:\Windows\System32`) or vice versa (putting it anywhere and adding the folder to PATH) was enough to make it work in Python.

Comment: Great answer. `sudo apt-get install phantomjs` worked for me in ubuntu tho. I had a failed install with npm previously.

Comment: To make node/npm working correct with Ubuntu add this package: apt-get install nodejs-legacy (https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs#im-on-debian-or-ubuntu-and-the-installer-failed-because-it-couldnt-find-node)

Comment: I managed to install PhantomJS on Ubuntu 16 using this command: `npm -g install phantomjs`

Answer (score 85):

PhantomJS recently [dropped Python support](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.5.html) altogether. However, PhantomJS now embeds [Ghost Driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver).

A new project has since stepped up to fill the void: [`ghost.py`](http://ghost-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You probably want to use that instead:

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()

with ghost.start() as session:
    page, extra_resources = ghost.open("http://jeanphi.me")
    assert page.http_status==200 and 'jeanphix' in ghost.content
```

Comment: Even though support is dropped, I found that installing npm (node package manager) and using it to install the latest phantomjs (with webdriver support) and installing selenium in python ... way easier than trying to get PyQT or PySide to work properly. What's nice about phantom it is truly headless and requires no UI/X11 related libs to work.

Comment: I added an answer below explaining my preferred solution after trying to use ghost.py and hating my life

Comment: Pykler's "hating my life" isn't an understatement. If someone would change the "correct answer" for this question to Pykler's I would have saved a day's effort.

Comment: @YPCrumble: unfortunately, only the OP can do that; change the accepted answer.

Comment: After trying a bunch of different approaches this morning, @Pykler solution ended up working the smoothest.

Comment: Though I don't like its syntax compared to PhantomJS, getting Ghost.py working with PyQT was bearable. I just had to change the code a little as mentioned here-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575181/screen-scraping-using-ghost-py   All in all, etting up Ghost.py was way easier than trying to get phantomjs working in selenium in python, which has proven impossible on a windows machine after hours of trying.

Comment: @Amalgovinus are you still using ghost.py or were you able to get phantomjs going after that [github issue you mentioned](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/236)?

Comment: @Pykler I gave up on ghost.py because it lacks cookies.. wound up using lorien's Grab library instead, even though it lacks js support. I did manage to get phantomjs dialing out after the fact (by tweaking constructor params) since I asked a question about it-- http://superuser.com/questions/674322/python-selenium-phantomjs-unable-to-start-phantomjs-with-ghostdriver -- but there were problems after that, so I stuck with Grab.

Comment: will ghost.py allow me to force the javascript on the page to load, so I can grab all the stuff (div, img, href, ) that the javascript loads on my page? i'm looking for a solution which I can then parse with Beautifulsoup (BS)

Comment: Ghost is headless? I don't see that anywhere in the project and given the pyside/qt dependency I'm doubtful.

Comment: @RyneEverett: Ghost is headless.

Answer (score 40):

Now since the GhostDriver comes bundled with the PhantomJS, it has become even more convenient to use it through Selenium.

I tried the Node installation of PhantomJS, as suggested by Pykler, but in practice I found it to be slower than the standalone installation of PhantomJS. I guess standalone installation didn't provided these features earlier, but as of v1.9, it very much does so.

1. Install PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/download.html) (If you are on Linux, following instructions will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267295/382630)
2. Install Selenium using pip.

Now you can use like this

```
import selenium.webdriver
driver = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://google.com')
# do some processing

driver.quit()
```

Comment: special thanks for pointing to SO answer concerning PhantomJS installation on Ubuntu, it helped me.

Comment: a quick way to install Selenium I just learned is, on Windows, type: C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install Selenium.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I test javascript using PhantomJS and Django:

**mobile/test_no_js_errors.js**:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    url = system.args[1],
    status_code;

page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
    console.log(msg);
    trace.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
    });
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(resource) {
    if (resource.url == url) {
        status_code = resource.status;
    }
};

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status == "fail" || status_code != 200) {
        console.log("Error: " + status_code + " for url: " + url);
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    phantom.exit(0);
});
```

**mobile/tests.py**:

```
import subprocess
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class MobileTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_mobile_js(self):
        args = ["phantomjs", "mobile/test_no_js_errors.js", self.live_server_url]
        result = subprocess.check_output(args)
        self.assertEqual(result, "")  # No result means no error
```

**Run tests**:

`manage.py test mobile`

Comment: Thanks. I used **subprocess.Popen** to call the phantomjs script and it worked :)

Comment: You do see how this is limited right? All you are doing is making a shell call to execute phantomjs - you are not actually using a "proper" interface through which you may properly handle exceptions, blocking, etc.

Comment: @kamelkev: I see how this is limited. The upside is that this method allows me to use Django's bootstraping features to set up a test database with the correct content for each test. And yes, it could be combined with the other answers to get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 6):

The [answer by @Pykler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699761/963195) is great but the Node requirement is outdated. The comments in that answer suggest the simpler answer, which I've put here to save others time:

1. Install PhantomJS

   As @Vivin-Paliath points out, it's a standalone project, not part of Node.

   Mac:

   ```
   brew install phantomjs
   ```

   Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install phantomjs
   ```

   etc
2. Set up a `virtualenv` (if you haven't already):

   ```
   virtualenv mypy  # doesn't have to be "mypy". Can be anything.
   . mypy/bin/activate
   ```

   If your machine has both Python 2 and 3 you may need run `virtualenv-3.6 mypy` or similar.
3. Install selenium:

   ```
   pip install selenium
   ```
4. Try a simple test, like this borrowed from the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage):

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

   driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
   driver.get("http://www.python.org")
   assert "Python" in driver.title
   elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
   elem.clear()
   elem.send_keys("pycon")
   elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
   assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
   driver.close()
   ```

Comment: How to install `PhantomJS` on windows ? It doesn't seem to work using `pip` command.

Comment: Pip is a python package installer, so it works with selenium, which is available as a python package. PhantomJS is not a python package so won't work with pip. I did a quick google for "PhantomJS install windows" and there are good hits.

Answer (score 5):

this is what I do, python3.3.  I was processing huge lists of sites, so failing on the timeout was vital for the job to run through the entire list.

```
command = "phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true "+<your js file for phantom>
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# make sure phantomjs has time to download/process the page
# but if we get nothing after 30 sec, just move on
try:
    output, errors = process.communicate(timeout=30)
except Exception as e:
    print("\t\tException: %s" % e)
    process.kill()

# output will be weird, decode to utf-8 to save heartache
phantom_output = ''
for out_line in output.splitlines():
    phantom_output += out_line.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to alter it to taste for my purpose.

Answer (score 5):

If using Anaconda, install with:

```
conda install PhantomJS
```

in your script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

works perfectly.

Comment: As of now, default channels don't contain PhantomJS for linux64

Comment: damn, i love conda <3  that was so easy.  i'm on osx.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/), you can easily automate the installation processes that Pykler describes using the [gp.recipe.node](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gp.recipe.node) recipe.

```
[nodejs]
recipe = gp.recipe.node
version = 0.10.32
npms = phantomjs
scripts = phantomjs
```

That part installs node.js as binary (at least on my system) and then uses npm to install PhantomJS. Finally it creates an entry point `bin/phantomjs`, which you can call the PhantomJS webdriver with. (To install Selenium, you need to specify it in your egg requirements or in the Buildout configuration.)

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('bin/phantomjs')
```

Comment: another way to automate installation process with buildout it's just use `gp.recipe.phantomjs`, that configures `phantomjs` and `casperjs`