# PhantomJS 1.8 with Selenium on python. How to block images?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Is there a way to configure PhantomJS webdriver on Selenium to do not load images? I know if I use phantomjs directly, I can start it with `--load-images=no` and it won't load the images, but how can I configure that via Selenium and Python?

UPDATE
Tried the following:

```
args = {
    'desired_capabilities': {
         'loadImages': False
     }
}
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(**args)
```

No success...

Answer (score 19):

Why are you not trying `webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--load-images=no'])` ?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: passing arguments is exposed, see the same answer mentioned below for how to do it

Passing arguments to phantomjs is not currently exposed with selenium's webdriver's init ... [I have worked around that by monkey patching the PhantomJS executer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699530/742390). Check that answer changing service_args to the following:

```
service_args += [
    '--load-images=no',
]
```

You could also opt to start the phantomjs server yourself, and just use the following call to point to an already running phantomjs at port 8080

```
# init the webdriver
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(port=8080)
```