# Make phanthomjs webdriver to stop loading CSS contents[ python crawler]

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have a python crawler which uses phanthomjs to crawl the sites and I am trying to stop loading 'css' contents from those webpages.I found a following code from various internet sources to stop 'CSS' loading, but that is not working .Please help me in fixing this issue.I also tried other solutions mentioned in stack overflow but that too didn't worked.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')
driver.execute('executePhantomScript', {'script': '''
var page = this;
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
 if ((/http:\/\/.+?\.css/gi).test(requestData['https://www.whatismyip.com/']) || requestData.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/css') {
        console.log('The url of the request is matching. Aborting: ' + requestData['https://www.whatismyip.com/']);
        request.abort();
}
''', 'args': []})

driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
ipaddress=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ip']").text
print ipaddress
driver.quit()
```

Comment: An alternative option could be to start up a proxy and let it filter out requests with text/css mimetype. And here is how you can specify it when initializing PhantomJS webdriver instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699718/how-do-i-set-a-proxy-for-phantomjs-ghostdriver-in-python-webdriver.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for you suggestion.I saw that link and it is describing how to set the proxy and already i have already  my proxy settings as follows `service_args = [--proxy=x.x.x.x:8080,'--proxy-type=http','--web-security=false','--ignore-ssl-errors=true','--local-to-remote-url-access=true',]      webdriver.PhantomJS.__init__(self,service_args=service_args,desired_capabilities=dcap)`  . Could you please suggest what change do i have to make in this settings

Answer (score 0):

You're testing the regex against `requestData['https://www.whatsmyip.com/']` which I'm assuming is `null` -- this is fixed by using `requestData.url` as per [the documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html). Also, a request will not contain a `Content-Type` so this conditional can be removed.

I chose to simplify your regular expression, since some URLs may be served with SSL or relative and will not match `http://`. I will use a `$` anchor to test for `.css` at the end of the URL (the `g`lobal modifier is not necessary, since you're only looking for one match).

Your final `.onResourceRequested` callback may contain a conditional like this:

```
if(/\.css$/i.test(requestData.url)) {
    request.abort();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort .I modified the code as follows but still it is not working.`driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')
driver.execute('executePhantomScript', {'script': '''
var page = this;
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
 if(/\.css$/i.test(requestData.url)) {
    request.abort();
}
''', 'args': []})

driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
ipaddress=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ip']").text
print ipaddress
driver.quit()` .

Comment: Do I have to make any other changes in above code,I am really confused in achieving this.