# Setting a proxy using python, selenium, and phantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, phantomjs

I have tried the solution posted by Alex on the following page but I keep getting this error.
[How do I set a proxy for phantomjs/ghostdriver in python webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699718/how-do-i-set-a-proxy-for-phantomjs-ghostdriver-in-python-webdriver/)

I have phantomJS in my PATH.

```
File "C:\Users\sri19\Desktop\Gui OSRS\testphantomproxy.py", line 21, in <module>
  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=phan_args, desired_capabilities=dcap)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
  self.service.start()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 86, in start
  self.assert_process_still_running()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 99, in assert_process_still_running
  % (self.path, return_code)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -1
```

Here is my current test script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import sys

singleproxy = "88.157.149.250:8080"
proxytype = "http"

user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) " + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36")

phan_args = ['--proxy=88.157.149.250:8080', 'proxy-type=http']
print "step 1"
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = user_agent
print "step 2"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=phan_args, desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
print "step 3"
print driver.current_url

htmlpage = driver.page_source
print htmlpage.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
```

Can anyone help me understand why I am receiving this error? When I applied this proxy to chromedriver (through a different method) it worked. So it cannot be the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp... Made a small mistake.

The following line
phan_args = ['--proxy=88.157.149.250:8080', 'proxy-type=http']
should be
phan_args = ['--proxy=88.157.149.250:8080', '--proxy-type=http']