# Installing phantomjs using npm error

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, phantomjs-node

I'm doing a unit testing for my javascript codes. I prefer to use a headless browser for easier running. It goes well when I installed some dependencies but when I install phantomjs, it has an error.

> C:\Phantomjs>npm install -g phantomjs npm WARN deprecated
>   phantomjs@2.1.7: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Plea se update
>   'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt' npm WARN
>   deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead npm WARN
>   deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie
>   h ttps://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
>   C:\Users.ra\AppData\Roaming\npm\phantomjs ->
>   C:\Users.ra\AppDa
>   ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs
>
> > phantomjs@2.1.7 install C:\Users.ra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ phantomjs
> >     node install.js
>
> Considering PhantomJS found at
>   C:\Users.ra\AppData\Roaming\npm\phantomj s.CMD Looks like an
>   `npm install -g` on windows; skipping installed version. Downloading
>   https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.1.1//phanto
>   mjs-2.1.1-windows.zip Saving to
>   C:\Users.ra\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-wind
>   ows.zip Using proxy http://.ra:******@proxy:3128/ Receiving...
>
> Error making request. Error: tunneling socket could not be
>   established, statusCode=502
>       at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Users.ra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
>   dules\phantomjs\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:165:19)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:320:30)
>       at emitThree (events.js:135:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:216:7)
>       at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:470:11)
>       at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:251:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
>
> Please report this full log at https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs npm
>   WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir
>   'C:\Users.ra\Ap
>   pData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'
>   npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir
>   'C:\Users.ra
>   \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'
>   npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir
>   \'C:\Users\p
>   ardillo.ra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules\dashda
>   sh\node_modules\'', npm WARN   errno: -4048, npm WARN   code:
>   'EPERM', npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir', npm WARN   path:
>   'C:\Users\.ra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
>   hantomjs\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules' } npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! phantomjs@2.1.7 install: `node
>   install.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   phantomjs@2.1.7 install script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional log ging output above.`

What should I do?

Comment: `Run as administrator`

Comment: Still the same @AyushGupta

Comment: what's your npm version?

Comment: npm --version is >> 5.4.2

Answer (score 2):

The simplest installation method is

1. Install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2. Using Node's package manager install phantomjs: `npm -g install phantomjs-prebuilt`

After installation, you may use phantom as simple as:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # or add to your PATH
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768) # optional
driver.get('https://google.com/')
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png') # save a screenshot to disk
sbtn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.gbqfba')
sbtn.click()
```

If your system path environment variable isn't set correctly, you'll need to specify the exact path as an argument to `webdriver.PhantomJS()`. Replace this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # or add to your PATH
```

... with the following:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')
```

References:

- [How do I set a proxy for phantomjs/ghostdriver in python webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699718/how-do-i-set-a-proxy-for-phantomjs-ghostdriver-in-python-webdriver/15699530#15699530)
- https://dzone.com/articles/python-testing-phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

Try run `npm install phantomjs-prebuilt`

**phantomjs** name changed to **phantomjs-prebuilt** on Pre-2.0 version release.

Source: [view this link for detailed description of the name change.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-prebuilt#versioning)