# PhantomJS' includeJs is not executed

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm new to phantomJS and this is what I tried so far:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);

page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://google.com', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log( 'Unable to access network' );
    } else {
        console.log( 'Opened ok' );
        page.includeJs( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
            console.log( 'include JS callback' );
            page.evaluate(function(){
                console.log('include JS callback - eval');
            });
        });
        console.log( 'After include JS' );
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

but the output is

```
The default user agent is Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34
Opened ok
After include JS
```

As you can see `'include JS callback'` and `'include JS callback - eval'` are not logged, where is the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fastest gun in the west Phantom-style problem. You're exiting too early. `page.includeJs` is an asynchronous function, because it has to send a request to fetch the resource. You can see that, because it has a callback. You should move the `phantom.exit();` to the end of the `page.includeJs` callback. All further processing should also be triggered from/moved to the `page.includeJs` callback.

If you want `'include JS callback - eval'` to appear you have to additionally register to the [`page.onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) event.

Comment: Just a link to this registration - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701208/phantomjs-page-evaluate-not-logging-onto-console

Comment: No, it was for others (if someone finds this in future), how to use this `page.onConsoleMessage`, I'm sure you know ;-)