# PhantomJS - page.evaluate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create()
        .then(function (ph) {
            _ph = ph;
            return ph.createPage();
        })
        .then(function(page) {
            _page = page;
            url = "http://www.aeiou.pt";
            return page.open(url);
        })
        .then(function(page) {

        console.log("hello3");
            page.evaluate(function () {
```

My code starts with something like this. The console.log "hello3" is printed but then, it gives me error:

> TypeError: page.evaluate is not a function
>       at /home/someone/server123.js:58:11
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Why it happens in this situation?

Node version: v8.6.0

Npm version: 5.3.0

Phantom version: phantom@4.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `page.open()` does not return the page -- it returns the status. So the value being passed to the next `then()` is the status, which you try to call evaluate on that. This, of course, doesn't work.

The way they handle this in their [example](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/blob/master/examples/simple.js) is have a page variable outside the `then()` chain that they can access inside each `then()`. You are almost doing that with `_page = page;` If `_page` is defined outside the function, you should be able to call `_page.evaluate()` rather than calling it on the return value from `open()`.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var _page;

phantom.create()
    .then(function (ph) {
        _ph = ph;
        return ph.createPage();
    })
    .then(function(page) {
        _page = page;
        url = "http://www.aeiou.pt";
        return page.open(url);
    })
    .then(function(status) {
        // check status for errors here
        console.log("hello3");
        _page.evaluate(function () {
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank's!

Comment: my question is solved but now, inside _page.evaluate(function() { I can't print anything, it seems that it there are any error... I tried to throw an error but without success. Any idea why?

Comment: Yeah, that's something that's a little tricky - the code you run in `evaluate()` is running in the context of the page you are evaluating. There's a good thread on the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701208/phantomjs-page-evaluate-not-logging-onto-console

Comment: @Mark_M  `page.set('paperSize', {format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait'});`
`page.set` is not a function any idea ?