# Python: Headless Selenium without admin access

Tags: python, selenium, headless-browser

I have a crawler in python that uses Selenium webdriver. I would like to start it in a cluster and leave it running for about 10 days. The problem is:

```
I do not have an X display!!!!
```

I have done some searching and reading. Normally this would be solved by using Xfvb and pyvirtualdisplay. It is not yet installed in the clusters. Now another problem pops up:

```
I do not have admin access in clusters!!!!
```

Although I can install pyvirtualdisplay in python VE, I cannot run

```
sudo apy-get install xvfb
```

I don't own a personal desktop. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect phantomjs to Selenium.

It needs no X display at all http://phantomjs.org/

connect it to your selenium grid server like this

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role hub &

#bit flaky if selenium isn't up quietly goes away
sleep 5
phantomjs --webdriver=4001 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444 &
```

To add more to it add them on extra ports

```
phantomjs --webdriver=4002 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444 &
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm asking something stupid. I simply don't have selenium-server-standlone-x.xx.x.jar. I import selenium.webdriver and do all I want in Python. Can I still use this javascript lib?

Comment: I think the answer here is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python - specifically the answer by @Pykler