# Using PhantomJS through Selenium with Python - WebDriverException error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using the following code, as recommended here: [Is there a way to use PhantomJS in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python).

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768) # optional
driver.get('https://google.com/')
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png') # save a screenshot to disk
sbtn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.gbqfba')
sbtn.click()
```

When I try to run it I get the following error:

WebDriverException - "Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver."

Apparently, this error can be solved by replacing the 3rd line with:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')
```

I'm using Windows7, and the path for me appears to be: "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs". I have tried using this and variations of it as the executable_path, but I still get the same error. I have also tried adding the folder location to the path. Nothing has worked. I suspect that I am missing something pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!

It was a slightly different location. The line I was looking for was:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs')
```