# How to launch several URIs in selenium without crashing firefox?

Tags: firefox, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of URIs (all of them belong to the same URL) saved in a file (about 2000).
I want to code a **`Python`** program in order to pass these URIs one by one to Firefox using **`selenium`** in order to check the presence of pictures on each URI (page). 
Is there a way to do that safely ? I mean, if I read every URI from the file and launch firefox with it, then after checking images is done I close firefox in order to open it again with a new URI read from the file then this could crash my system/firefox at least for a while. 
How can I make firefox visit all my URIs without lanching it and closing it for each new URI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not close the browser after visiting a link, use [`get()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) call to load the page in the same browser session.

```
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    # check for presence of pictures
```

Comment: the kind alecxe has answered me again. I made a short test with 2 urls and you are right: both pages are visited without firefox being closed.

Comment: @begueradj hope it helped. Besides, you probably want to make it faster - consider using a headless browser like `PhantomJS` instead of `Firefox`.

Comment: @begueradj [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15699761/771848) should help with a setup.

Comment: On my project, I am forced to use firefox, but I may use PhantomJs for future steps in special needs.

Comment: I kept my promise :) Thank you very much for your (former) precious help (even if this one is also important to me). Regards

Comment: @begueradj This is really nice of you :) Thank you.