# How to use Tornado CurlAsyncHTTPClient to fetch web pages until it fully loaded and js has executed

Tags: python, web-crawler, tornado, nonblocking

I tried to build a Tornado application that could provide RESTful APIs to craw web pages. And I found that `CurlAsyncHTTPClient` cannot fetch a fully loaded page or a js-generated page.

Are there any solutions to this problem? Is there a library that could fetch fully loaded pages or js-generated pages and work with Tornado's non-blocking mechanism?

I would appreciate if you can provide any suggestions or solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

The http client (whenever it is from Tornado, async, curl, simple, requests, ...) makes a request to given resource and fetches the response - nothing more, no parsing response, executing.

Instead you want fetch response, parse it, download all dependencies (js), execute/render it in the right order. Basically you will need to **write a browser or use one**.

There are many [implementations of headless browser](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) (mostly based on webkit). The worth noting (in python) is [Ghost.py](https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py) and selenium (with phantomjs) - [Is there a way to use PhantomJS in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python).

The main drawbacks, in the context of your question, is they do not support Tornado's in any way (http client as a mechanism to making requests, and so on).  So I would, personally, drop Tornado for this task.

With PySide (Qt) - dirty example without Tornado:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebPage


class DownloadPage(QWebPage):

    html = ''

    def __init__(self, url, app, parent=None):
        QWebpage.__init__(self, parent)
        DownloadPage.html = ''    
        self.loadFinished.connect(app.quit)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))

    def save(self):
        DownloadPage.html = self.mainFrame().toHtml()


def get_page(url):
    app = QApplication.instance() 
    if not app: # create QApplication if it doesnt exist
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dp = DownloadPage(url, app)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(dp.save)
    app.exec_()
    return DownloadPage.html
```