# BeautifulSoup Div Class returns empty

Tags: string, python-3.x, class, beautifulsoup

I checked similar questions, but could not find a solution...

I'm trying to scrape the minutes of extra travel time (46) from the following page: https://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/trafficindex/city/istanbul

I've tried by 2 methods (Xpath & find class), but both give an empty return.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml.html import fromstring

page = requests.get("https://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/trafficindex/city/istanbul")
tree = fromstring(page.content)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')



#print([type(item) for item in list(soup.children)])

html = list(soup.children)[2]

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class_": "big.ng-binding"})

congestion = tree.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/text()")
print(congestion)
print(len(g_data))
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Many thanks for helping out!

Comment: The class you are searching for does not seem to exist on the page you are lookig for it.You might also like to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138085/how-to-wait-for-page-load-to-complete) entry...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately `BeautifulSoup` alone is not enough to accomplish it. The website uses JavaScript to generate content so you will have to use additional tools like for example `Selenium`.

```
import bs4 as bs
import re
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/trafficindex/city/istanbul'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)           
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

I can see two approaches to extract extra time:

1.Looking for `div` with `class="text-big ng-binding"`.

```
div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'text-big ng-binding'})
result = div[0].text
```

2.Finding `div` containing `Per day` text first and then going two divs up

```
div = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Per day'))
result = div.find_previous('div').find_previous('div').text
```

Comment: This solution works, but why does it open Firefox every time?
I don't want to open it.