# BeautifulSoup find() returns tags, but no value between the tags. Why is this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

The code I'm using is straightforward enough:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

re = requests.get('https://bitcointicker.co/stamp/btc/usd/1hr/')
print(re.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.content, 'lxml')
value = soup.find(id="lastTrade")
print(value)
```

However, the print(value) line produces the following:

```
<div id="lastTrade"> </div>
```

Which is quirky because the element inspector on the website shows the following:

```
<div id="lastTrade">3420.140</div>
```

What's going wrong when the script attempts to access the value encased in the div? I have a suspicion that there's something related to security and data privacy going on, but I don't currently know anything related to that.

Comment: See: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737796/beautifulsoup-div-class-returns-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737796/beautifulsoup-div-class-returns-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code, you will see that the value is not there:

```
<div id="lastTrade">&nbsp;</div>
```

The value is dynamically generated. You should use `selenium` or a similar web driver to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different url and extract the last value which is the same (although the site continually polls to update). If you have the original website open and monitor the title at the same time you run the request you should briefly see a match.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

re = requests.get('https://bitcointicker.co/getHistCur.php?mins=60&cur=USD&exch=stamp')
items = re.json()
print(items[-1]['price'])
```

Comment: this will be faster than opening a browser.