# "Clicking" button with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, bots

I have this little website i want to fill in a form with the requests library. The problem is i cant get to the next site when filling the form data and hitting the button(Enter does not work).

The important thing is I can't do it via a clicking bot of some kind. This needs to be done so I can run in without graphics.

```
info = {'name':'JohnJohn',
        'message':'XXX',
        'sign':"XXX",
        'step':'1'}
```

First three entries name, message, sign are the text areas and step is I think the button.

```
r = requests.get(url)
r = requests.post(url, data=info)

print(r.text)
```

The Form Data looks like this when i send a request via chrome manually:

- name:JohnJohn
- message:XXX
- sign:XXX
- step:1

The button element looks like this:

```html
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
    <input name="step" type="hidden" value="1">
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick="myClick();"
     style="background-color: #ef4023;  width: 80px; font-face: times; font-size: 14pt;">
        Wyślij
    </button>
</td>
```

The next site if i do this manually has the same adres.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you might see from the snipped you posted, clicking the button is triggering some JavaScript code, namely a method called `myClick()`.

It is not straightforward to click on this thing using pythons requests library. You might have more luck trying to find out what happens inside `myClick()`. My guess would be that at some point, a `POST` request will be made to a HTTP endpoint. If you can figure this out, you can translate it into your python code.

If that does not work, another option would be to use something like Selenium/PhantomJS, which give you the ability to have a real, headless and scriptable browser. Using such a tool, you can actually have it fill out forms and click buttons. You can have a look at this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699761/2822762), as it shows you how to use Selenium+PhantomJS from python.

Please make sure not to abuse such methods by spamming forums or [insert illegal or otherwise abusive activity here].

Comment: How could i figure out what is happening inside myClick()? Also isn't Selenium something like emulating physical clicks so i would need to have a browser open etc? I would like to avoid that. 

It's mostly for educational purposes. I'm interested with bots (Good ones) and webscraping.

Comment: PhantomJS is a headless browser, meaning that there is no window open, it's just a running process. A chrome process can be started in a similar fashion. Since you are getting served the `.js` files that are required for the page, just open the Chrome Dev Tools and find the right one in the "Resources" Tab.

Comment: How do I know where the myClick() is making a POST request? @Dave

Comment: @KranthiKiran You have to find the definition of `myClick` and see what it does.

Comment: @KranthiKiran I use Firefox (and I assume chrome devtools has this option) but if you look at the `network` tab, you can see the requests being made after clicking javascript elements.  I have a question (similar to the author's) that I am trying to tackle without selenium or PhantomJS because I want my app to be light (and I want to learn more about requests).

Answer (score 5):

In such a situation when you need to forge scripted button's request, it may be easier not to guess the logic of JS but instead perform a physical click and look into chrome devtools' network sniffer which gives you a plain request made which, in turn, can be easily forged in Python

Comment: Can anyone provide an example for a "Load more" button? I need to understand the research process behind that, and so far I'm stuck at dev tools on the browser > Network > XHR > a Post request and viewing the Response. New to AJAX / JS scraping.