# Python click button with requests

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to 'click' a button on a site with the requests module on a website, but I can't get it working.

This is the button on the site:

```
<div data-expected-currency="1" data-asset-type="T-Shirt" class="btn-primary btn-medium PurchaseButton " data-se="item-buyforrobux" data-item-name="T-Shirt" data-item-id="307054354" data-expected-price="2" data-product-id="28239339" data-expected-seller-id="96294876" data-bc-requirement="0" data-seller-name="All Player Clothing">
                                         Buy with R$
                                    </div>
```

This is what I've been trying to do in  Python:

```
urlattempt = 'https://www.roblox.com/NewLogin'
    values = {'Username': 'USER',
      'Password': 'PASSWORD',
              'action': 'login'}
    rpost = requests.post(urlattempt, data=values)
    cookies = rpost.cookies
    values2 = {'action': 'btn-primary btn-medium PurchaseButton'}
    rpost2 = requests.post('https://www.roblox.com/item.aspx?id='+price2, cookies=cookies, data=values2)
```

The login part works fine, it's just the last part (from values2) that doesn't works.

Answer (score 2):

`Clicking` a button is not directly possible with the requests library. If you really need to `click` on something from your python code, you need a scriptable, possibly headless browser.

What you *can* do, is to figure out what request goes to the server when the button is clicked and try to recreate it using `requests`. Use your browsers developer tools to inspect what requests are made and what contents they have. I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37167063/2822762).

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use the selenium library

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe',options=options)
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try session, so that it will carry cookies when you change to another page in the same site. Here is how it looks like:

```
import requests

s=requests.session()

url_login=''
url_data=''

payload={'**strong text**':'usrname','Password':'pswd'}
request1=s.post(url_login,data=payload) # this is to pass the 

request2=s.get(url_data)
```

As for clicking a button, you may need to find out the action behind the button.  There might be a handler against an element Id.