# executable file build with cxfreeze not working in other systems?

Tags: python, phantomjs, exe, cx-freeze

I have created a simple application with pyqt4 which uses phantomJS.When I build the python file with cxFreeze it creates a executable file.When I run the executable file in my system it runs because PhantomJs is installed in my computer.When I tried in other systems It fails.It might be because PhantomJS might not be installed in their computers. What I have to do in order run my application in other computers because most of the users dont have PhantomJS installed in their computers.
Chat Con

Comment: do you make a system call or are you using it through pure python modules (as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python)?