# HTML to Pdf using Phantom.js in Django

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am working in a GIS app and I have to present the result of a dataset in HTML, but the HTML file is too large.

I now want to convert it to PDF using phantom. Does anyone have a working example?

Comment: You can get "working examples" from Google, if you want us to help you need to show us what you've tried already. We won't write your code for you.

Comment: I know @GGG but mostly I got which are implemented by using Node.

Comment: @tousifNoor okies good almost is not complete  ,, [Google reference](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js)

Comment: Maybe this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15699761/2671392 along with this http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html