# how to scrape internal-pages of a website that requires login

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch my attendance by a python script, so for that I was first supposed to login to my id and then go to the attendance tab. So I sticked the `href` of the attendance button to my college website, and used

```
start = requests.session()
attendance = start.get(url=url_that_ attached,data=data_of_my_login and some additional_info)
```

But its giving me a stop sign when I'm trying to fetch it's content. How I'm supposed to click on that attendance button. The button looks like this.

```
<li><a href="../Student/StudentAttendanceView.aspx?SID=Z5iKNRYtbRzca2kr9KIG9g==|9ZPIo+QpZxY=" id="aAttandance">Attendance</a></li>
```

And this is the content I'm getting instead the attendance webpage.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>
   <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><img src="images/stop-sign-small2.jpg" /></center>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a stop sign. Is there any other way to click on the attendance button like by its name i.e `Attendance` is there any way that opens the tab by its button name and I don't want to use selenium for that. I'm using python 3.

Comment: First login using `post` method instead of `get`.

Comment: For clicking button check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15699761/3968623)

Comment: i already did the login ,the question is after the login, and as i said in the question , i don't want tt use `PhantomJS` ,selenium thanks for the answer though