# Python3 JavaScript web scraper

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Does Python3 have a JavaScript based scraping library that is not Selenium? I'm trying to scrape `https://www.mailinator.com/v2/inbox.jsp?zone=public&query=test`, but the inbox is loaded with JavaScript. The reason I don't want to use Selenium is I don't want it to open a window when I run it.

Here is my non-working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
INBOX = "https://www.mailinator.com/v2/inbox.jsp?zone=public&query={}"
def check_inbox(name):
    stuff = soup(requests.get(INBOX.format(name)).text,"html.parser")
    print(stuff.find("ul",{"class":"single_mail-body"}))
check_inbox("retep")
```

Do any such libraries exist?

I couldn't find anything for the Google search `python 3 javascript scraper` outside of Selenium.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: @Hum4n01d this is python3, not python.

Comment: I don't see why that would make a difference.

Comment: different syntax, libraries aren't compatible

Comment: Ok, but overall the solution is still going to be the same. You need a library that renders the page with JavaScript before you start scraping.

Comment: I would like a *python3.x* library that works. I can't use *python2.x*.

Comment: One possible approach is to see if PhantomJS has Python 3 bindings. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python). Your question may benefit though from an explanation as to why you wish to avoid Selenium.

Comment: since it's websockets, you'll have no luck with phantomjs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript actually, because it's client side, so you can emulate it.

If you inspect the webpage (developer tools > network), you'll see that there is a `websocket` connection to this :

```
wss://www.mailinator.com/ws/fetchinbox?zone=public&query=test
```

[image: Webpage inspection]

Now if you implement a websocket client using python, you'll be able to cleanly fetch your mails (see this : https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/example/client.py).

**EDIT :**

As mentioned by John, augustin's ws client repo is dead.
Today I'd use this : https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: hmm... it's not working for me - `websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: Status code not 101: 500`

Comment: ```import websockets, asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
INBOX = "wss://www.mailinator.com/ws/fetchinbox?zone=public&query=test"
async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect(INBOX) as ws: 
        response = await ws.recv()
        print(response)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())```

Comment: that's an internal server error. But it's another topic. I'd suggest you make another question with what you are trying, and why it doesn't work.
My guess is, you have to send some headers (maybe the cookies).
Also you should look at the source code, and see how they do their websocket connection. Maybe you have to register to a channel.
Also, try a bit more than 5 minutes before asking the community ;)

Comment: select `WS` filter, that stands for "websockets"

Comment: I noticed that one of the headers is changing every time - `Sec-WebSocket-Key`. How would I go about generating one of these?

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the source code, and see how it's done in javascript so you can emulate it.
But really that'll be my last comment on that topic, open a new question when you have something to show with what you try if needed, link it here if you'd like, i'll give it a look.
But then you seem to be on the good path, look for that `Sec-Websocket-Key`

Comment: @Loïc the github link is broken, do you have a code snippet you could add to your answer?