# How do I check if a website is responsive using python?

Tags: python, html, css, web-crawler

I am using python3 in combination with beautifulsoup.

I want to check if a website is responsive or not. First I thought checking the meta tags of a website and see if there is something like this in it:

`content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0`
Accuracy is not that good using this method but I have not found something better.

Has anybody an idea?

Basically I want to do the same as Google did it here: https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly reduced to the output if the website is responsive or not (Y/N)

Comment: There's no easy way doing this. What I would suggest as the best option is static CSS and HTML analysis. Unfortunately, as far as I know, there's no already existing library that will do this for you, but you can more-or-less easily make one which will trace patterns of responsive design on client side, when scrapping.

Comment: I guess we can find the responsiveness of website source code by reading and searching for media queries in the code like '@media'. If these css media queries are found in the source code it will be responsive in nature with combination of checking the meta tag as well.

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.website.com").read()
soup = bs(source, "lxml")
head = soup.head
if "@media" in head.text:
    print("Responsive")
else:
    print("Not Responsive")`

I have got to check the accuracy but do you have something to add already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Just a suggestion)

I am not an expert on this but my first thought is that you need to render the website and see if it "responds" to different screen sizes. I would normally use something like `phantomjs` to do this.

Apparently, you can do this in python with `selenium` (more info at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699761/3727050). A more comprehensive list of technologies that can be used for this task can be found [here](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers). Note that these resources seem a bit old/outdated and some solutions fallback to python subprocess calling `phantomjs`.

The linked google test seems to

- Load the page in a small browser and check:

  - The font-size to be readable
  - The distance between clickable elements to ensure the page is usable

I would however do the following:

- Load the page in desktop mode, record each div's style.
- Gradually reduce the size of the screen and see which percentage of these change style
- In most cases, from a large screen to a phone size you should be seeing 1-3 distinct layouts which should be identifiable from the percentage of elements changing style

The above does not guarantee that the page is "mobile-friendly" (ie usable in a mobile) but it shows if the CSS are responsive.