# phantomjs: unknown module system

Tags: phantomjs

Phantomjs version 1.4 (the newest version available through apt). I have a single js file, with this content:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
```

When I run it, with:

```
phantomjs testscript.js
```

I get the error:

```
undefined:0 Unknown module system for require()
```

What does this mean? What causes it? I was trying to run the example from https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/direction.js, but I can't seem to get the simplest thing to work. Is there another way to read command line arguments than using system?

Comment: just download the current version and use that. v1.4 is ancient. they have binaries

Comment: What OS are you trying to use?

Comment: @JustEngland Ubuntu - Linux 3.3.6-030306-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version (1.9.1). See: [How can I setup & run PhantomJS on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778513/how-can-i-setup-run-phantomjs-on-ubuntu)

Or compile your own version:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath git-core libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.9
./build.sh
```

Note you need to symlink to /usr/bin/ etc from your build dir