# installing PhantomJS on docker/Dokku container

Tags: phantomjs, docker, dokku

I am having a few issues with adding PhantomJS to our website docker containers.

I got 2 containers test and production but have no idea how to add it to each of these containers.

The containers are made with Dokku and are already running. This is a bit different so we are not able to pull up fresh containers with images or edit their Dockerfiles

Additionally we have managed to use commands like `wget` in them using `dokku run`, but this is not an interactive shell. Also the files downloaded with wget don't appear to be in the container when checking with `ls` even though the download finishes.

Comment: You should be able to just add [the binary](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) into the `PATH`, no?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: this is much easier than I thought.

What you need to do is use this dokku plugin:

https://github.com/F4-Group/dokku-apt

Once the plugin is installed, just create an apt-packages file in the root of your project. See more info in the README

Comment: This works great. The apt-packages file just needs to have the text "phantomjs". Dokku will install phantomjs on deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Taking cues from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267295/378143) answer from SO, you can put the same lines in your Dockerfile while building the containers. That should do it.
HTH

Comment: In dokku you don't get direct access to the Dockerfile, but you can pass options via the docker-options plugin