# How do I install the phantomjs binary?

Tags: linux, unix, phantomjs

I've downloaded and unzipped the phantomjs binary, but I don't know how to set it up.

I've tried adding it to my path in .bashrc and copying it to usr/bin, but it's still listed as uninstalled when I type in `which phantomjs` at terminal.

Any ideas on how to make it available at the system level?

Thanks!

Comment: [this Question is good guide ,this is about install  ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778513/how-can-i-setup-run-phantomjs-on-ubuntu

Comment: Is the file executable?  Run `chmod 755 <filename>` to make sure.

Comment: `chmod` executed without problem

Comment: I tried to copy the binary into `user/bin` directly but it said there was already an identical copy, meaning my symlink is working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks ahmeddeep007 for a link to the eventual fix. I tried hacking things with a few different symlinks, moving the binary to user/bin, etc., but the eventual solution was also the simplest.

`sudo npm install -g phantomjs`

I use npm locally for managing project dependencies, but it didn't jive that I could just add the `-g` flag until I saw it somewhere else.