# WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Running Selenium locally on flask. Im using the PhantomJS driver. I previously had a path error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

But after finding out from another StackOverflow question, I learned that I have to pass the environment path as a parameter for PhantomJS. The path I have below is the path to the phantomJS folder in my virtual environment folder.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/Users/MyAcc/Documents/MYWEBAPP/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs')
```

However, I get a new error-code now:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

Here's what I get when I check the file permissions of the path.

```
total 40 
drwxr-xr-x 7 USER staff 238 Nov 6 00:07 . 
drwxr-xr-x 17 USER staff 578 Nov 6 00:03 .. 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 USER staff 6148 Nov 6 00:07 .DS_Store 
-rw-r--r-- 1 USER staff 787 Oct 31 12:27 __init__.py 
drwxr-xr-x 5 USER staff 170 Oct 31 12:27 __pycache__ 
-rw-r--r-- 1 USER staff 2587 Oct 31 12:27 service.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 USER staff 2934 Oct 31 12:27 webdriver.py
```

Comment: and what permission has this file when you list directory `ls -al` - `rwxrwxrwx` ?

Comment: `total 40`

`drwxr-xr-x   7 USER  staff   238 Nov  6 00:07 .`

`drwxr-xr-x  17 USER  staff   578 Nov  6 00:03 ..`
`-rw-r--r--@  1 USER  staff  6148 Nov  6 00:07 .DS_Store`
`-rw-r--r--   1 USER  staff   787 Oct 31 12:27 __init__.py`
`drwxr-xr-x   5 USER  staff   170 Oct 31 12:27 __pycache__`
`-rw-r--r--   1 USER  staff  2587 Oct 31 12:27 service.py`
`-rw-r--r--   1 USER  staff  2934 Oct 31 12:27 webdriver.py`

Comment: did you solved the issue? Thasnk you

Answer (score 2):

I placed the phantomjs file into `/usr/local/bin` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Well I got this solved by the following CODE:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = "/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/bin/phantomjs")
```

Comment: it also works for me in windows 10. the "phantomjs" in the end is phantomjs.exe, not a fold.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem before about python+phanomjs. 
solution:

**Linux**

putting phantomjs in `/usr/local/share`

**Windows**

putting phantomjs in `/python/scripts`

Answer (score 1):

I think the true reason for you problem is that: **The phantomjs which webdrive needs is not the one under `selenium/webdriver` fold**. When you use anaconda to install this package, it's really confusing (at least for me).

- First install it with `conda install -c conda-forge phantomjs`, test it with `phantomjs --version`.
- Then you can find the true phantomjs.exe in this fold: `"path = /${home_path}/anaconda3/envs/${env_name}/bin/phantomjs"`. To test if it's the true path, test with `/${home_path}/anaconda3/envs/${env_name}/bin/phantomjs --version`. It should output `__version__` information correctly.
- Pause this path to `webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path)` and it will be fixed.

So there's no need to use `chmod` or put it in `/usr/local/bin` (in this way, the only goodness is that you can skip the `executable` parameter)

Answer (score 0):

```
executable_path = './phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs'

service_log_path = './log/ghostdriver.log'

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=executable_path, service_log_path=service_log_path)
```

You can use both the relative path and absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable may have wrong permissions.

This error is because phantomjs didn't execute permission, as long as for phantomjs - 2.1.1 - Linux - x86_64 / bin/phantomjs add execute permissions, chmod u + x phantomjs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, do not post answer twice, edit your first answer  and make the changing there, spend some time reading [how to write an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Strangely, for me it was fixed by putting phantomjs in `/usr/local/share` and adding some symbolic links. I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778513/how-can-i-setup-run-phantomjs-on-ubuntu):

- move the phantomjs folder to `/usr/local/share/`:

  - `sudo mv phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 /usr/local/share/.`
- create the symbolic links:

  - `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.8.1-linux-x86_64 /usr/local/share/phantomjs`
  - `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.8.1-linux-x86_64 /usr/local/share/phantomjs`

I'm no Linux expert so I don't know why this makes a difference. If anyone wants to pitch in, feel free.