# Failed to install phantonjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: phantomjs

After following the [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267295/6154399) on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, And finally when I do

`phantomjs -v`

I get the error:

```
Auto configuration failed
140111765546944:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libproviders.so): libproviders.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
140111765546944:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
140111765546944:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=providers, path=providers
140111765546944:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=providers
```

`

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Disable OpenSSL 3 configuration loading by running it as:

```
OPENSSL_CONF= bin/phantomjs
```