# running phantomjs in mac

Tags: java, macos, path, phantomjs

I'm trying to use phantomjs on OSX and doesn't work using two approaches:

1. Using the file downloaded from http://phantomjs.org/download.html on the Downloads folder and 
   unzipping it...When running the app that needs phantomjs I get the error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phantomjs": error=2, No such file or directory

2. I installed phantomjs and executed, based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448459/phantomjs-not-working):

> sudo ln -s /path/to/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/

but it is already installed:

> ln: /usr/local/bin//phantomjs: File exists

How can I make this work?

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Where did you have `phantomjs`? What is the result of `ls -lt /usr/local/bin/phantomjs`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer....The result is: **lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  52 Jun 23 21:16 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs -> /Applications/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs**

Comment: And the result of `head -n 1 /Applications/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs`?

Comment: results: **head: /Applications/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs: No such file or directory**

Comment: Then you don't have `phantomjs` there. Looking at your linked thread, you seem to be missing `bin` somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for this but...how do I install it there?

Comment: Generally, drag the phantomjs.app to your Applications folder.

Comment: I cannot find the phantomjs.app file to drag...I've tried everything...the last thing I tried was **git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.9
./build.sh** I'm kinda lost here...got that from [here](http://phantomjs.org/build.html)

Comment: Per [here](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2012/02/phantomjs-and-mac-os-x.html), This is the fastest and easiest way. Go to the download page, find the ZIP file for Mac OS X, then download it.

Comment: I download it and unzip it in the "download" folder of my mac as the instructions say and nothing happens...still doesn't work...sorry for bother so much with

Comment: The Mac version? Did you get an app file? if not, you didn't get the correct zip file.

Comment: version 10.7.3...apparently there is no .app file...I have the bin folder with phantomjs inside (is this .app?), examples folder and a few licence files

Comment: Hi....can you help me out anymore here? Or no more ideas? Thanks!!